# Intent Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS is not working on 4.1.2 and 4.2 Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm launching `Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS` intent in my application. It works for most of the devices I'm having except **4.1.2** and **4.2**. Whenever I try to launch above intent in this devices, setting apps is getting force closed, and also its causes my app to stop running.

Is there any way that I can check before launching `Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS intent`? Or at least can prevent stopping my application? 
I have already tried putting `startActivity(Intent)` inside try-catch block. But that is not the problem here, since Setting activity is exist and its crashing while executing `onCreate()`.

Here is the stack trace:

```
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.settings/com.android.settings.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at com.android.settings.DeviceInfoSettings.onCreate(DeviceInfoSettings.java:98)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5017)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2035)
08-14 17:38:37.984: E/AndroidRuntime(9905):     ... 11 more
08-14 17:38:37.984: W/ActivityManager(658):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that I can check before launching Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS intent?

Unfortunately, no, because the `Intent` is working -- you are tripping over some bug in the Settings app on those devices.

> Or at least can prevent stopping my application?

There should be no effect of this crash on your application. The Settings app is crashing, not you. The crash dialog will appear over your app, but your app should be otherwise unaffected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But my app is also getting close by Android ActivityManager. Here is the stack trace:  08-14 17:38:37.984: W/ActivityManager(658):   Force finishing activity com.android.settings/.Settings$DeviceInfoSettingsActivity
08-14 17:38:37.994: W/ActivityManager(658):   Force finishing activity com.my.android.mynext/.activities.MYActivity

Comment: @Audumbar: That's certainly disappointing. I don't know why Android would be force-finishing your activity in this case. You are welcome to use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` or something as a crude filter to try to avoid starting this activity on versions that are giving you trouble. Or, consider solving your problem in some other way (e.g., show the data you want from this Settings screen yourself, if it is data accessible via the SDK).

Comment: Correct. Even I tried launching setting intent in different task: actionIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); But still it is failing. Anyways thanks CommonsWare.

Comment: As you suggested I'm using Build.VERSION.SDK_INT to check for version 16 & 17, and not calling startActivity(intent). Its working fine for me. But in some 4.1.2 devices, intent Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS is working. So now my problem is how to differentiate between this two devices? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Audumbar: "So now my problem is how to differentiate between this two devices?" -- I have no idea. If the problem was that the device did not support the `Intent` action, and you got an `ActivityNotFoundException`, there would be approaches to take to handle that. But in your case, the Settings app claims to honor that action, then crashes, and I do not know any reliable way to determine ahead of time that this will be the case.

Comment: Yes, You are correct. There is no reliable way. Thanks!